# placeholder text is not coming with bullet in IE.working fine with chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying show the placeholder text in the following way in IE8:

"Any relevant reference numbers, such as Direct Debits:-
- Name of the Branch (if applicable) 
- What was the original problem 
- Date the problem occurred "

The above is coming fine in Chrome but in ie it is looking like:
Any relevant reference numbers, such as Direct Debits:-Name of the Branch (if applicable) - What was the original problem - Date the problem occurred

can anyone help me to show the placeholder text in above formatted way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't support HTML input placeholder attribute, for details click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp).

Comment: Is there any alternative of this problem..??

Comment: Bring this feature using javascript/ jquery.